# Alternative to Facebook FBML based multi friend selector

Tags: facebook, fbml, invite

As Facebook has deprecated FBML, Multi friends selector does not work now.
[Request dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) support only canvas URLs and not web sites. 
[Send dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) is one option but does not provide the same features as a Multi friends selector.
There are some other alternatives outside but I would prefer to use something from Facebook stable.

Can anybody suggest something on this?
I need to implement it on a Java EE based page dedicated domain and not on a Canvas app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have just two options: use one of those alternatives you were you talking about or implement it yourself.

Comment: Implementing it yourself is not that hard at all – have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/ That’s a client-side example in JavaScript, but the principle can most easily be transfered to any server-side language as well.

Answer (score 0):

Requests Dialog, can be used for a dedicated domain also, not only Canvas Apps,
search for `redirect_uri` in the examples here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I have answer a similar question here:
[Alternative to the default friend picker?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10725142/alternative-to-the-default-friend-picker/10726887#10726887)

Comment: I saw the page that you mentioned but probably this is not what i asked for. I understand that i can use it for a dedicated domain but once a user receives the app request and clicks on the invite, he is being redirected to a facebook page which has my website embedded in it. I am looking for a complete redirection to my website.

Comment: This is something else that you haven't wrote on your question, the Requests Dialog works fine on a dedicated domain. Please correct your answer according your specification. Also for your problem, you can add a redirect in the canvas app to your domain.

Comment: Also, if you run the app on a dedicated domain, why you use the Canvas? If you remove this from your application options you will be redirected on your domain.